# Possible to set a variable per if else statement?

Tags: jquery

I use the following function to set my event tracking with google.
For this, I takte the breadcrumbs-Text to set the Source Page.

I get an 'unexpected identifier'-error

What I want to do is

1. On the START page, there is no breadcrumb, so the sPage value should be "Source Page Start".
2. If the user opens an other site, the sPage value should be "Source Page mk-breadcrumbs-text.

Thank you, Cheers

```
    jQuery(function () {
    var sPages = jQuery('.mk-breadcrumbs-inner').text();
    var sPage_name = "Source Page ";
    if (sPages.value = '') {
        sPage = sPage_name + "START";
    } else if sPages = sPages.replace("START / ", "");
    sPage = sPage_name + sPages;

}

   jQuery('a, mk-button, menu-item').on('click', function () {
    var jE = jQuery(this);
    var sAct = 'Clicked ';
    var sTarget = 'Target Page ';
    var sVal = sTarget + jQuery.trim(jE.text());
    if (jE.hasClass('mk-button')) {
        sAct += 'Button';
    }
    console.debug(sPage + '; ' + sAct + '; ' + sVal);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an

```
else if
```

without condition!

Either you insert a condition, or you remove the word **if**.

Solution 1:

```
   if (sPages.value = '') {
      sPage = sPage_name + "START";
    } else if(sPages.value = 'foo') {
      sPages = sPages.replace("START / " , "");
      sPage = sPage_name + sPages;
    }
```

Solution 2:

```
 if (sPages.value = '') {
   sPage = sPage_name + "START";
 } else {
  sPages = sPages.replace("START / " , "");
  sPage = sPage_name + sPages;
 }
```